# Why does assignment in a binary search algorithm not add to the time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o, binary-search

Take the worse case for insertion sort where there is an array of *n* decreasing elements. The total time spent **comparing** all element, from left to right, is:

1 + 2 + ... + (n - 2) + (n - 1)

Also considered in calculating the time complexity is **swapping** those elements, which is also:

1 + 2 + ... + (n - 2) + (n - 1)

Ultimately, we arrive at O(n^2).

Take another algorithm like binary search; **the act of finding a midpoint**, and then after comparing to that midpoint, **reassigning your midpoint** to `high` or `low` during each division of the list in half doesn't count at all towards the time complexity. Only the act of comparing the midpoint to the target value. **So why does swapping in classic sorting algorithms, which are three assignment statements, impact the time complexity but the assignments of the midpoint in binary search do not?**

---

**UPDATE**

As [Taylor Edmiston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149428/taylor-edmiston) pointed out,

> n the binary sort, lookup is cheaper in a tree structure vs insertion sort where the data structure is an array/list. The pathological case for the insertion sort is every element having to be swapped past every single other element already in the list.

But isn't "swapping" really just three variable assignments?

```
if (a[i] > a[j])
   x = a[i];    
   a[i] = a[j];    
   a[j] = x;
```

How are those three assignments any more or less of a dominating factor than the following that you see in a general binary search algorithm?

```
while(low < high)
   mid = (low + high) / 2;    // assignment 1
   if (data[mid] == target) 
      return true;
   if (data[mid] < testValue)
      low = mid + 1;          // assignment 2_a
   else
      high = mid;             // assignment 2_b
```

Comment: It's the differing underlying data structure.  In the binary sort, lookup is cheaper in a tree structure vs insertion sort where the data structure is an array/list. The pathological case for the insertion sort is every element having to be swapped past every single other element already in the list.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Please elaborate :) From my understanding, there isn't any swapping involved with a binary search algorithm due to the condition that the data must be sorted. I'm unfamiliar with the idea that "swapping is cheaper in a tree structure"

Comment: You are right — just fixed my typo s/swapping/lookup for the binary search tree (BST).  Lookup in the BST is cheap because binary search continually halves the search space with each iteration (it will never need to do n checks because the data structure is already sorted vs insertion sort which is dealing with sorting data that is unsorted).  Check out the Wikipedia article for a visual and more detailed description.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Isn't the point of BST being halved have more to do with the comparison? Example: Compare 14 items; not found? Compare 7 items; not found? Compare (3,4) items; not found? Etc. O(log(n)). But in the process, there is still assignments going on to keep the algorithm fresh with each iteration. I updated my question,

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston I reworded the question header itself. I think maybe that'll clear up what I am confused about. Thank you for working with me on this!

Comment: Yep, I was a bit imprecise above.  The cost is not in the swap itself but in the comparison operations that check all of the other numbers that leads up to the swap.  You can call the whole process comparing/swapping.  You might find this visual demo of insertion sort helpful.  https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting?slide=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do !

In insertion sort, you perform O(n²) comparisons and O(n²) assignments, and the total is still O(n²).

In binary search, you perform O(Log n) comparisons and O(Log n) assignments and the total is still O(Log n).

But it is common practice, when you know that some operation is performed in proportion of another (i.e. in binary search, one assignment per comparison), to only count one type of operation.

By the way, think that there are other operations that were not accounted for, such as array dereferences or loop statements. Using the big-Oh notation, we don't care, as long as the numbers of operations remain proportional (or of a lower order of magnitude).

---

**Additional example:**

One can implement insertion sort with a binary search followed by swaps.

In such a version, you would perform approximately

Log 1 + Log 2 + Log 3 + Log n-1 comparisons, which is O(n Log n),

and still O(n²) swaps. Globally, the algorithm behavior is O(n²).

In the complexity analysis, you could dispense yourself with counting the comparisons, as they enter into play with a lower order of magnitude, and only care about the assignments. *Provided this imbalance is established* !

Answer (score 0):

There's no one, consistent, measure of time complexity.

For sorting algorithms, basic operations are considered to be comparisons (and nothing else). The same is true for hash table operations -- it counts the number of comparisons done. "The time complexity of mergesort is O(n log n)" is better understood to mean "mergesort does O(n log n) comparisons". And "A hashtable lookup is O(1) on average" is better understood to mean "a hashtable lookup performs O(1) comparisons on average".

That's necessary to keep things simple -- for example, if you sort an array of strings, the string comparisons are not O(1) in basic operations -- the cost depends on the length of the strings. If you try to ignore this and say "let's assume that our computer can perform comparisons in O(1)", you find sorting algorithms that can perform less than n log n basic operations. I have a [(rather technical) blog post about this](https://blog.paulhankin.net/complexity-rant/), including some references to the (even more technical) literature.

When considering other algorithms, you may measure basic operations (for example, assignments, arithmetic operations, etc.). Even then, sometimes you might consider the cost of an arithmetic operation to be constant, or dependent on the size of the operands.

Nearly all use of casual complexity theory ignores the differences in what "time" means, and people will happily combine and compare different analyses using different notions of time. That works out fine in practice and gives useful results, but it's not theoretically sound.

Comment: I disagree. The asymptotic complexity evaluation is perfectly well defined. It is based on the enumeration of all constant-time operations, whatever they are. And a simple rule is used: if the count of some operation *dominates* the other counts, it suffices to use the former. O(n Log n) can be understood as "no elementary operation is performed more than C n Log n times, for some constant C", but no particular operation is referred to. This definition is universal.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think that definition is universal. For example there are different cost models (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Cost_models) that don't assume constant costs. And the theory of sorting algorithms can't use this definition, since the n log n lower bound for time complexity and "comparisons are constant time" are inconsistent beliefs -- if you assume comparisons are constant time, you can sort an array of items (each of size log n), in less than O(n log n) time. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000093900404 .

Comment: There are indeed different models (though not so many), but the main idea remains: you count the constant-time operations. By the way, comparisons of bounded size items of any type is O(1).